# C# Selenium WebDriver Hangs on same page

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, remotewebdriver

No matter if I do a FindElement. Or on the Wait.Until.

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver.Instance, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
wait.Until(d => d.Title == pageTitle);
```

I get the following error:

> OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebdriver.Title.Get timed out and needed to be apborted in an unsafe way. This may have corrupted the target process.

It says one way to fix it is to click on the 'enable property evaluation and other implicit function calls'...but that doesn't help. Just hangs and gives me a less detailed message. What could cause the hangup on Just trying to get the Title of a page? I need help to look in a new/correct direction, so far I have been hitting dead ends.

Chrome -- Version 76.0.3809.100

Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver version 76.03770.....going to upgrade this one...to be closer

Comment: Usually these things are the result of a mismatch between the web driver version and the version of the browser you are interacting with.

Comment: See updated edits...for that information..adding now

Answer (score 0):

Giving Credit where Credit is due....I thought I had these synced up..... I did not..from one greg to another...thank you.

***Usually these things are the result of a mismatch between the web driver version and the version of the browser you are interacting with. – Greg Burghardt***